# storing VDOM in a Map?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, dom

Some thoughs on VDOM and their storage in Maps, just in case of...

Consider a VDOM production, like this :

```
h('div', { class: "list" }, [
  h('div', { class: "list-item" }, [
    h('span', {}, item.name),
    h('button', { value: 'Add To Cart', onclick: addToCart(item.id), []})
  ]),
  // ... lots of items
])
```

My question is about storing the resulting N-ary tree in a Map, with identical blocks like :

```
class Block { 
  constructor (uuid, parentUUID, leftSiblingUUID) {
    this.uuid = uuid
    this.parent = parentUUID
    this.leftSibling = leftSiblingUUID
    this.firstAttrUUID = // some UUID
    this.data = {}
  }
}
```

Blocks are identical in their structuren, no matter if you store a "div" or one of its attributes. The whole DOM tree is stored in a Map. Keys are 32-bits (4 bytes) unsigned integers like: 0xbada55e5, tested against unicity.

Corollaries :

- a bit of overhelming memory use: 4 bytes * number of pointers per block, but :
- access to a block is time-constant (due to the Map)
- NO DIRECT OBJECT CIRCULAR REFERENCIES,
- a flatten data structure, allowing easy serialization and deserialization mechanisms,
- MAYBE some easing with the diff/patch algorithms

What's you opinion ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is probably an opinion based question.

Comment: it's also a try, a wandering, an other way to do the job, if I succeed !

Comment: Well yes you can implement your own pointers fairly easily, but do you also implement your own garbage collector?

Comment: JavaScript has no "*32-bits (4 bytes) unsigned integers*". But yeah, a plain array (instead of a `Map`) and usual integer indices would suffice as well.

Comment: https://github.com/hefeust/domulo is a first code attempt to solve my own  question !